# Why a short rope takes more load than a longer rope?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, elasticity, string

[image]

The captain of a ship told me that it should be avoided to put a long rope next to a short one because the short rope takes most of the load and the long becomes relatively inactive, although both ropes are taut.

Does anybody knows the reason for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you were thinking about, but I think if you ignore the nonlinear behavior, you can model the string as a classical spring, where the force exerted by the spring is $F=k \Delta x$, and $k$ is a constant, $\Delta x$ is the change in the length of the spring/string. After that, it's obvious that the shorter string is exerting a stronger force, because if the 2 strings are stretched to the same length, the shorter one'll show a greater change in length. But the nonlinearities  in the strings' forces may decrease the actual difference between the forces exerted by them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorter rope will have a larger extension than the longer rope to maintain the condition that both ropes are taut. Generally, any long piece of rope/string/wire etc. will have a tension proportional to the extension.

Answer (score -3):

Its probably because of the old saying "a chain is only as strong as its weakest link". A chain with 100 links has a greater probability of having a weak link than a chain with 10 links. Likewise with a rope. A rope 50 m long has a greater chance of having a weakness than a rope of 2 m.

Comment: I thought the chain argument was very convincing.  All it takes is one weak link.  Much more likely to occur with more links.

Comment: You are answering the question of which rope is more likely to break if they are subjected to the same tension. The question being asked is why there is more tension in the shorter rope.

Comment: there isn't more tension in shorter rope.

Comment: why the down vote. My answer is not wrong and may well be correct!

Comment: @jmh it's not wrong: the logic about the higher probability of a weak link is correct. However, it can't be used to explain this situation: your logic is for the same force on 2 separate strings. Here, we're focusing on the division of force among the 2 ropes, and intuitively, it makes no sense if you say that a long rope next to a short rope is bad because the long one is more likely to break under those circumstances. That being said, I didn't downvote it because while it isn't an answer, it does offer something to think about in a more general situation.